# How to implement Pivot control for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I just love the pivot control design in windows mobile. I would love to implement similar kind of design in my application, just like [Skype app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype-for-iphone/id304878510?mt=8) for iOS (PFA screenshot below). I did look up to check whether is there any libraries in github to do this. But I didn't find one. So please give me a head start on how can this be achieved. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use the UISegmentedControl and UIScrolllview together to get the look and feel of the Pivot control. But the solution I came up with was little clumsy and cranky and wasn't smooth at all.

But when I was browsing github again to find whether there is any existing solution for this I came across this library [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu). This is the closest solution I could find, using which you can get the look and feel of Pivot control. Take a look at the attached screenshot.[image]

I had to do lot of look up to get this library, so I hope this may come in handy if someone who is looking for a similar kind of design. Hope this helps :)